# SQL Server Indexing a View that decrypts a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption, view, indexing

I'm currently trying to index my view so it doesn't take as long to query against. To simplify things, I'll give an example of my setup.

I currently have a `Person` table. In the person table, I store a person's encrypted `birthdate` (stored as a `varbinary`) among other things. I have also made a view called `vPerson` that decrypts the column and displays it as a normal date. For reference, I decrypt the `birthdate` in the select statement like this..

```
CAST(DECRYPTBYKEYAUTOASYMKEY(ASYMKEY_ID('NameOfKey'), NULL, BirthDateEncrypted) AS DATE) AS BirthDate
```

I have to use `DecryptByKeyAutoAsymKey` because it doesn't require you to open a key to use it (since a view is just the 1 select query). This works fine on its own, but once I try to create an index for the view with the code..

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX Idx_vPerson ON dbo.vPerson (PersonID);
```

it gives me this error..

> Cannot create index on view '**_**.dbo.vPerson'. The function 'AsymKey_Id' yields nondeterministic results. Use a deterministic system function, or modify the user-defined function to return deterministic results.

I'm very confused, because I believe it is a deterministic function as it always returns an `int`. If I hover, it even says it returns an `int`. Maybe I'm just misunderstanding something about the whole process, but if anyone can enlighten me or give some insight I would very much appreciate it!

Comment: Why bother encrypting the data if you create a view that automatically decrypts it? That pretty much defeats the purpose doesn't it?

Comment: Well, the Birthdate is encrypted in the database using keys based on the service master key. AKA, If someone somehow got a backup copy of the database, there's no possible way to read it unless they also acquire the service master key.    Edit: To clarify, the Service master key is specific to an instance of SQL Server, where-as a database master key is specific to a database. When you make a backup of a database, it does not carry the service master key with it, but it does carry database master keys, asymmetric keys,  etc.

Comment: If you look [at the MSDN documentation for `DecryptByKeyAutoAsymKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365420.aspx), it clearly states that the return type is *`varbinary` with a maximum size of 8,000 bytes.*

Comment: The decrypt function does, but the function AsymKey_Id, which sql seemed to be complaining about from the error, returns and int. Both of them non-deterministic though. My issue in this problem was that I didn't completely understand deterministic and non-deterministic functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DecryptByKeyAutoAsymKey` is not deterministic because it doesn't always return the same result when called with the same arguments. That's because you can reconfigure the key `NameOfKey`. Indexed views require deterministic functions.

> If someone somehow got a backup copy of the database, there's no possible way to read it unless they also acquire the service master key.

And that makes the function non-deterministic.

Actually, it would be possible to extract the data out of the index without any key. A database backup is enough.